# After unlocking light-locker, screen remains blank proportional to how long it's been locked

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, screensaver, x, light-locker

Weird problem that I've been having I think since I installed Linux Mint 19. I run xfce and light-locker is my screen locker. Whenever I unlock my screen with my password, my screen remains black for a time before showing me the desktop.  From what I can tell, while it's black, my desktop is accessible and I can mouse over things and see the cursor change, even open menus, etc. It's just all black. Eventually the desktop shows up and everything is fine.

Another odd aspect of this problem is that the screen remains black for a proportional time to how long it's been locked. The longer it's been locked, the longer it remains black after unlocking. So for instance if I lock the screen for a few minutes, the screen only remains black for a second, but if I lock it for a day, it remains black for a minute.

I checked the .xsession-errors and syslog and couldn't find any clues. I've upgraded packages, rebooted, etc. and nothing seems to fix it.  Anyone experienced this before or have an idea?  I'm running the nouveau video drivers with a GeForce GTX 1050 and a GeForce GT 610 installed with three screens.